# Can I install Ubuntu on HFS+ file system?

Tags: hfs+

I already have my HDD partition formatted for Mac OS X, but I don't want to format it again. Is it possible to install Ubuntu on this Mac formatted HFS+ file system?  **I don't want to use a virtual machine.**

Comment: Why would you have to format it again? The Ubuntu installation will do it for you.

Answer (score 4):

No, Ubuntu cannot be installed on this filesystem as you described, and since you don't want to use a VM (virtual machine) you will have to format the partition to a filesystem developed for Linux, such as ext4.